# Makefile / mingw32/Id.exe can not find static library

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, static-libraries, mingw32

Thanks for your time.
I can not include the static openssl library into my makefile everything is working but only without the library. I am getting the error message.

```
strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/. /i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto-1_1 and -lssl-1_1
```

INCDIRS contains Header Files, CXX and LINKER using gcc and CFLAGS is "-g"

```
INCDIRS := -I/$(inc)

# LIBS: Include new Library
LIBS = lib/-lssl-1_1 lib/-lcrypto-1_1

# Generate a list of .cpp files, which is stored 
# in the SRCDIR directory.
SRCFILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)

# Patsubst function generate a list of .o files.
OBJFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCFILES))

# Generate a list of .d (dependency) files, that is
# produced by the compiler. Stored in the OBJDIR directory.
#DEPFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SRCFILES))

# Start
$(BINDIR)/$(PROGRAM): $(OBJFILES)
    $(LINKER) $(CFLAGS)  $(INCDIRS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)    

# Bbuild a .o file in the OBJDIR directory from a .cpp file
# in the SRCDIR directory.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $< -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: I think you need `-L DIRECTORY_WHERE_LIBS_ARE -lcrypto-1_1 -lssl-1_1`

Comment: Change your makefile to LIBS = -L<path to your ssl-1_1> -L<path to your crypto-1_1> -lssl-1_1 -lcrypto-1_1

Comment: go to /usr/lib and see if these to libraries are present or not in your system. They will named as libcrypto and libssl with .so extension. If they are present then add -L /usr/lib to LIBS. If they are not present then you need to install them.

Comment: I changed LIBS += -L/lib/-lssl-1_1  , LIBS += -L/lib/-lcrypto-1_1 because  /lib stores libcrypto-1_1.a and libssl-1_1.a. It is not working. Thanks for reply

Comment: No, `-L XYZ -lABC` is the way to say *"link to library ABC in directory XYZ"*.

Comment: Now, it's working. Thanks